# How to run gradle tasks --info

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I've seen some people asking for Gradle related problems on Stackoverflow getting answers like "run `gradle tasks --info`"

How do I run that? Where do I type this?

EDIT: I tried using the Terminal feature of Android Studio and did the following:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject>gradle tasks --info
'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject>
```

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error happened because you tried to run a gradle command without config your gradle in your PATH. To avoid this you may configure your path in your windows or you can run the command using the gradle wrapper.

Open your project directory: [image]

You will see this file named **gradlew**, now you can run:

On Windows:

> C:\Users\User\Desktop\MyProject>gradlew tasks --info

On Linux or OS X:

> /your/directory/MyProject $ ./gradlew tasks --info

Answer (score 2):

Use the terminal (on mac)/cmd (on windows) and navigate into the project folder or if you are using AndroidStudio there is an integrated terminal.

At the bottom of the page near the Android window
[image]

Comment: the integrated terminal is n the project folder?

Comment: There is a Terminal feature in Android Studio

Comment: okay, thanks, I've also edited my question with what happened

Answer (score 1):

```
gradle tasks --info
```

Change `gradle` to `gradlew`;